# Image transfer over Websocket to WebGL Vs Canvas and maybe with workers

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, websocket, webgl

All I am  receiving images via ArrayBuffer over Websocket and posting it on canvas. about 10 images a sec (say 500x500 PNGs)

Would actually posting to WEBGL be faster. 
Again  I am not going to do any rotations/transformation.

Just simple display a lot of images one after another.

because it uses GPU/Shaders would WebGl be a faster way ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Video chat? If so use WebRTC. If you say why you're trying to send 10 images a second over WebSockets people might be able to suggest other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most canvas2d implementations already use hardware-acceleration, so when you only want to place simple images on a canvas, WebGL will only introduce much more technical complexity without gaining you anything.

It can make sense to use WebGL for 2d graphics when you want to do some complex image filtering operations, because a shader can perform them on the GPU while your only way to do pixel-level operations with canvas2d is to load the graphic to the RAM with getImageData, do the operation on the CPU, and load it back to the GPU with setImageData.

When you have performance problems, I think that your bottleneck might be here: *"about 10 images a sec (say 500x500 PNGs) via Websocket"*. A 500x500 PNG is at least 200kb, but can be a lot larger depending on content and how well the compression algorithm is chosen. 10 images per second take at least 2MB per second which are at least 16 MBit/s of bandwidth. Do you have that much bandwidth?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Images are random sizes so it can be 10x10 to 500x500. Say I do 10x10 images. Sometimes my browser gets faster and sometimes slowdown randomly and picks up. Maybe it is a memory leak on browser side. Thanks